# Two strings between brackets separated by a comma in C++

Tags: c++, string, parentheses, comma-operator

I came across unexpected (to me at least) C++ behavior today, shown by the following snippit:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << ("1", "2") << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2
```

This works with any number of strings between the parentheses. Tested on the visual studio 2010 compiler as well as on codepad.

I'm wondering why this compiles in the first place, what is the use of this 'feature'?

Comment: c++ has a comma operator http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/c-comma-operator

Comment: Figured it would be a duplicate, it didn't occur to me to search for a comma operator. Thanks for all the answers anyway!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ahh, this is the comma operator. When you use a comma and two (or more) expressions, what happens is that all expressions are executed, and the result as a whole is the result of the last expression. That is why you get "2" as a result of this. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) for a bigger explanation.

Answer (score 8):

It's called the comma operator: in an expression `x, y`, the compiler
first evaluates `x` (including all side effects), then `y`; the results
of the expression are the results of `y`.

In the expression you cite, it has absolutely no use; the first string
is simply ignored.  If the first expression has side effects, however,
it could be useful.  (Mostly for obfuscation, in my opinion, and it's
best avoided.)

Note too that this only works when the comma is an operator.  If it can
be anything else (e.g. punctuation separating the arguments of a
function), it is.  So:

```
f( 1, 2 );      //  Call f with two arguments, 1 and 2
f( (1, 2) );    //  Call f with one argument, 2
```

(See.  I told you it was good for obfuscation.)

Comment: "Mostly for obfuscation, in my opinion, and it's best avoided" - a classic and reasonable use is to modify multiple variables in `for` loops, e.g. `for (; x > y; x--, y++) ...`

Comment: @TonyDelroy I did say _mostly_.  I'm not sure that I wouldn't prefer a `while` loop in the case you site, but it's certainly a case where it is arguably acceptable.  The other "widespread" use is in macros, where it can be used to make two statements appear as a single function call, or to "coerce" a void function (e.g. `abort` to a given type, so that it can be used in a ternary operator.

Answer (score 3):

**Comma operator ( , )**
  The comma operator (,) is used to separate two or more expressions that are included where only one expression is expected. When the set of expressions has to be evaluated for a value, only the rightmost expression is considered.

For example, the following code:

```
a = (b=3, b+2);
```

Ref:http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/

Comment: Crucially, the comma operator introduces a sequence point, ensuring that each of the expressions from left to right are executed in order, so `b=3` will definitely have executed before `b+2` begins (at least from the perspective of observable behaviour).

Comment: exactly.
in this case, a = 5, b = 3.

Answer (score 1):

The result of the comma (",") is the right subexpression.
I use it in loops over stl containers:

```
for( list<int>::iterator = mylist.begin(), it_end = mylist.end(); it != it_end; ++it )
  ...
```

Comment: Except that there's no comma operator in your example.

Comment: @JamesKanze I think he's missing the variable name after the first iterator declaration and the type declaration for `it_end`, but they are separated by a comma...

Comment: They are indeed separated by a comma, but I think James meant that this comma is not "operator comma" but it's rather part of a variable declaration list. James, thanks for pointing it out, I will read about it.

Comment: @AlexanderChertov Exactly.  Most commas are not operators, but part of the general syntax.  The difference is very important; if you overload the comma operator, the overload will only be taken into account in contexts where the comma actually is an operator.  (Not that overloading the comma operator is a good idea, unless your goal is obfuscation.)

Answer (score 0):

The comma operator evaluates the expressions on both sides of the comma, but returns the result of the second.