# OpenCV display the wrong color

Tags: c++, opencv, rgb

I am working with OpenCV using C++. I would like to create an image with 3 colors: red, white and black. In detail, I want the background red and then a part white and a part black based on some conditions.

The problem that I have is that when I set a color to white it becomes BLUE.

Could someone know why this happen and how to solve it?

This is my code:

```
    //initial image total red

    cv::Mat image(Size(w, h), CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255));          

    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
            int pixel_v = (int)imggray.at<uchar>(i,j);
            if (pixel_v < 200) {                
                int pixel_bl = (int)imgBool.at<uchar>(i, j);
                if (pixel_bl > 200) {
                    //HERE A WANT WHITE PIXELS, but they are blue
                    image.at<Vec3b>(i, j) = (255, 255, 255);                        
                }
                else {
                    //black: this works
                    image.at<Vec3b>(i, j) = (0, 0, 0);

                }
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: OpenCV displays the right color but you feed it the wrong values.

Comment: Try: image.at<Vec3b>(i, j) = cv::Vec3b(255, 255, 255);

Comment: nuzhny: Yes, it is called because I change the color of those pixels! They became blue instead of white

@Swordfish: It could be. What is the right value for white in opencv? isn´t (255,255,255)?

Comment: `(255, 255, 255)` does not do what you think it does (see [comma operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do).) It evaluates to just `255`.

Comment: I misread what you were setting `(255, 255, 255);` is wrong.

Comment: Read here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23001512/c-and-opencv-get-and-set-pixel-color-to-mat The other commenters are eluding to this being the problem

Comment: @Moira and why it works for the other colors? So, if it is how you are saying what should I do to set the color to white?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV uses the image format BGR (Blue, Green Red)

When you write this line:

```
 image.at<Vec3b>(i, j) = (255, 255, 255);
```

it is equivilent to:

```
image.at<Vec3b>(i, j) = (255);
```

(See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899009/two-strings-between-brackets-separated-by-a-comma-in-c) to explain why.)

Which only sets the first channel, to max and that happens to be blue.

What you need to do is edit the whole pixel, like this:

```
    // get pixel
    Vec3b color = image.at<Vec3b>(Point(x,y));

    color[0] = 255;
    color[1] = 255;
    color[2] = 255;

    // set pixel
    image.at<Vec3b>(Point(x,y)) = color;
```

[Borrowed from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23001512/c-and-opencv-get-and-set-pixel-color-to-mat)

So your code would need to look like this:

```
cv::Mat image(Size(w, h), CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255));          

for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
        int pixel_v = (int)imggray.at<uchar>(i,j);
        if (pixel_v < 200) {                
            int pixel_bl = (int)imgBool.at<uchar>(i, j);
            if (pixel_bl > 200) {
                //HERE A WANT WHITE PIXELS, but they are blue
                Vec3b color = image.at<Vec3b>(Point(i,j));
                color[0] = 255;
                color[1] = 255;
                color[2] = 255;
                image.at<Vec3b>(Point(i,j)) = color;                   
            }
            else {
                image.at<Vec3b>(i, j) = (0, 0, 0);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works but in this way 

Vec3b color;
color[0] = 255;
color[1] = 255;
color[2] = 255;
image.at<Vec3b>(i, j) = color;


Thank you very much for the explanation about the first channel.

Comment: That's great, yes you don't need to read out the color to start with. You could even move the Vec3b color definition outside the loop to save creating a new object each time and it will be quicker.

Answer (score -1):

[image: The kind of images I'm getting.]

I'm using opencv with C++. I recieve an image from java and then make it into a buffer using this method:

```
private fun YUV_420_888_dataToBuffer(image: Image): ByteArray? {
     try {
   val imageWidth = image.width
   val imageHeight = image.height
   val planes = image.planes
   val data = ByteArray(imageWidth * imageHeight *  ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel(ImageFormat.YUV_420_888) / 8 )
   var offset = 0
   for (plane in planes.indices) {
       val buffer = planes[plane].buffer
       val rowStride = planes[plane].rowStride

       val pixelStride = planes[plane].pixelStride
       val planeWidth = if (plane == 0) imageWidth else imageWidth / 2
       val planeHeight = if (plane == 0) imageHeight else imageHeight / 2
       if (pixelStride == 1 && rowStride == planeWidth) {
           // Copy whole plane from buffer into |data| at once.
           buffer[data, offset, planeWidth * planeHeight]
           offset += planeWidth * planeHeight
       } else {
           // Copy pixels one by one respecting pixelStride and rowStride.
           val rowData = ByteArray(rowStride)
           for (row in 0 until planeHeight - 1) {
               buffer[rowData, 0, rowStride]
               for (col in 0 until planeWidth) {
                   data[offset++] = rowData[col * pixelStride]
               }
           } 
           buffer[rowData, 0, Math.min(rowStride, buffer.remaining())]
           for (col in 0 until planeWidth) {
               data[offset++] = rowData[col * pixelStride]
           }
       }
   }
   return data
  } catch (e: Exception) {
   return null
 }
    }
```

On the c++ side I'm creating a Mat from the byte array like this:

```
 Mat * myuv = new Mat(width, height, CV_8UC1, (unsigned char *)  data);

 cvtColor(*myuv, *myuv, COLOR_YUV420sp2RGBA, 4);
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Please open your own question instead of commenting under another question.